# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments. Why is _init()_ missing arguments when it's there?

Tags: python, oop, typeerror

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self,vehicle_cost,vehicle_type):
        self.__vehicle_id =None
        self.__vehicle_type=vehicle_type
        self.__vehicle_cost=vehicle_cost
        self.__premium_amount=None


    def set_vehicle_id(self,vehicle_id):
        self.__vehicle_id=vehicle_id

    def get_vehicle_id(self):
        return self.__vehicle_id

    def set_vehicle_type(self,vehicle_type):
        self.__vehicle_type=vehicle_type

    def get_vehicle_type(self):
        return self.__vehicle_type

    def set_vehicle_cost(self,vehicle_cost):
        self.__vehicle_cost=vehicle_cost

    def get_vehicle_cost(self):
        return self.__vehicle_cost

    def set_premium_amount(self,premium_amount):
        self.__premium_amount=premium_amount

    def get_premium_amount(self):
        return self.__premium_amount

    def display_vehicle_details(self):
            print("Vehicle Id is",self.__vehicle_id)
            print("Vehicle Type is",self.__vehicle_type)
            print("Vehicle Cost is",self.__vehicle_cost)

    def calculate_premium(self):
        if(self.__vehicle_type =="Two Wheeler"):
            self.__premium_amount=self.__vehicle_cost-self.__vehicle_cost*0.98
            print(self.__premium_amount)
        elif(self.__vehicle_type =="Four Wheeler"):
            self.__premium_amount=self.__vehicle_cost-self.__vehicle_cost*0.94
            print(self.__premium_amount)
        else:
            print("Error: Wrong Vehicle type")


obj=Vehicle(105000, "Two Wheeler")
obj.calculate_premium()
```

Comment: As you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the full exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help. I cannot replicate your issue - output `2100.0`.

Comment: Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Agree with @AChampion The output for me is also `2100.0`

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: are you testing it from python console while editing it in parallel?

Comment: Yes, i am getting the desired output as 2100.0 . But, the platform has several inbuilt test cases. None of the logical lest cases is passing stating the error TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'vehicle_cost' and 'vehicle_type'. What could possibly be missing ?

Comment: Unless you provide the test code and the full exception we will not be able to help you. Please [edit] these details into your question.

Comment: Just a hint: Python is not Java. You don't have to write setters and getters for everything. Iff you need special behaviour, use a `property`

Answer (score 1):

If u stop passing any values through init method so every attributes are initialized as None and then just rely on set method for passing value to attributes might solve the problem.

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__vehicle_id =None
        self.__vehicle_type=None
        self.__vehicle_cost=None
        self.__premium_amount=None


    def set_vehicle_id(self,vehicle_id):
        self.__vehicle_id=vehicle_id

    def get_vehicle_id(self):
        return self.__vehicle_id

    def set_vehicle_type(self,vehicle_type):
        self.__vehicle_type=vehicle_type

    def get_vehicle_type(self):
        return self.__vehicle_type

    def set_vehicle_cost(self,vehicle_cost):
        self.__vehicle_cost=vehicle_cost

    def get_vehicle_cost(self):
        return self.__vehicle_cost

    def set_premium_amount(self,premium_amount):
        self.__premium_amount=premium_amount

    def get_premium_amount(self):
        return self.__premium_amount

    def display_vehicle_details(self):
        print("Vehicle Id is",self.__vehicle_id)
        print("Vehicle Type is",self.__vehicle_type)
        print("Vehicle Cost is",self.__vehicle_cost)

    def calculate_premium(self):
        if(self.__vehicle_type =="Two Wheeler"):
            self.__premium_amount=self.__vehicle_cost-self.__vehicle_cost*0.98
            print(self.__premium_amount)
        elif(self.__vehicle_type =="Four Wheeler"):
            self.__premium_amount=self.__vehicle_cost-self.__vehicle_cost*0.94
            print(self.__premium_amount)
        else:
            print("Error: Wrong Vehicle type")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error on my side. Your code is correct and it gave me output 2100.0.

Try to rename your file and make a new file with .py extension and run with **python filename.py** command on console instead of trying directly on console.